# How do I find the sum of a given list for x[i]≥ a fixed x value, for each x value?

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

The code block is supposed to do the following:

- Find `sum(all y_values in the list if the index corresponding to that y value has an x_value which is ≥ a fixed x_value)`. Find this sum for all x_values in the order given by the list, and append it to a list of its own.
- The output should be a list with the same length as len(x_values).

For example:

input:

```
x_values = [1,2,3,3,4,5]

y_values = [9,4,3,1,2,1]
```

output should be:

```
[20,11,7,7,3,1]
```

Note: I'm using python3.

```
my_list = []
my_list2 = []
for j in range(len(x_values)): 
    for i in range(len(x_values)):
        if x_values[i] >= x_values[j]: #x_values[j] is supposed to be fixed x_value
            my_list.append(y_values[i])
            my_list2.append(sum(my_list)) #my_list2 is supposed to be such that len(my_list2)=len(x_values)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Get out of the habit of using `for index in range(len(list)):`. Use `for item in list:` or `for index, item in enumerate(list):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be calculating `sum(my_list)` every time through the inner loop. You should initialize `my_list` each time through the outer loop, and calculate the sum after the inner loop.

However it can all be replaced with a single list comprehension and a generator in the `sum()` argument.

Use `zip()` to loop through `x_values` and `y_values` together, to get the `y` values in the corresponding indexes as the `x` values that are compared with `fixed_x`.

```
result = [sum(y for x, y in zip(x_values, y_values) if x >= fixed_x) for fixed_x in x_values]
```

Comment: Hello!
This code gives incorrect output. Maybe I should clarify -- the y_values should not be used in any calculation. All x_values should be compared to a single x_value for each loop. Here, you're comparing entries in the y_values to entries in the x_values.

Comment: Sorry about that, got confused between inputs and outputs. But the structure is the same, just change the variable names.

Comment: Which variables? I provided an example of what the output should look like given an example input.

Comment: I mistakenly thought `y_values` was one of the inputs, not the output. I corrected the answer to loop through `x_values` twice -- once in the `sum()` generator and also in the list comprehension.

Comment: I understood the question, just got confused while writing the answer.

Comment: The code still doesn't give the correct output. 
The x_values should be evaluated against fixed x_values. If the x in x_values is larger than the fixed x_values, we want that index. Then, we want sum(y_values[index]) for each fixed x_value.

The end result should be a list of these sums.

example input:
x_values = [1,2,3,3,4,5]
y_values = [9,4,3,1,2,1]
example output:
[20,11,7,7,3,1]

Comment: Sorry, now I got it. I tested this and it worked.